# Is it possible to import data from AWS DynamoDB table into Microsoft SQL server?

Tags: python, sql-server

I want to import  data from dynamodb table  into SQL Server.

I use Python botot3.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to use [pymssql](https://pypi.org/project/pymssql/):

> A simple database interface for Python that builds on top of FreeTDS
> to provide a Python DB-API (PEP-249) interface to Microsoft SQL
> Server.

You create a connection:

```
conn = pymssql.connect(server, user, password, "tempdb")
cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
```

Then you can [use](https://pymssql.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/pymssql.html) `execute` or `executemany` to built an `ISNERT` statement.

It will be better if you are able to save this data in CSV file and then use [BULK INSERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) statement as it will be faster if you are working with large amount of data.